# C Linker issue, building for macOS-arm64, linking with file built for macOS-x86_64

Tags: c, linker-errors, arm64

When trying to link and run C written on someone elses machine, I am given the warning below:

ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libpng.dylib, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64

I am running this on a Mac m1, and it works on other machines running with a Mac m1.

Any ideas of how to resolve the issue? Thank you!

Comment: That's a warning, not an error.

Comment: The library in question was built for x86_64 rather than arm64, what part of that is unclear?

Comment: It looks like lingering libraries from, most likely, an install ported over from an x86_64 machine.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.